# How to automatically add files to app folder?

Tags: android, android-file, android-update-app

I'm trying to add files(images) to the app folder when my app is installed and every time if there is any update, I'd like to add more files to the app folder. How can i achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Regards,
Dexter

Comment: Which files? Which images? Which folder? There is no such thing as "app folder" in Android. Updates to what? Can you edit your question and give some precise information so we can try and help you.

Comment: @adelphus The app folder is the top-level folder when you're developing. You're not supposed to put anything in it, but it does exist.

Comment: @adelphus The files or images doesn't matter here as it can be anything. As for the app folder, I'm referring to the folder where you can see when you are developing in the IDE. In my case its eclipse.My question is how can i refer to those folder? The only folder i can access so far is just assets folder.

Comment: @camdroid, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you put in the apk is what the user gets. If you add images, then submit the update to Google Play, your users will have those images when they update.

Although your images should be in res/drawable, not in the app folder.

Comment: I don't mind placing it in any folder if it works. I've get it a try thanks.

Comment: If the images aren't inside the drawable folder, you might not be able to reference them inside your code. Just so you're aware.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to add files(images) to the app folder when my app is installed

That is not possible, as nothing of your code will run when your app is installed. You are welcome to detect when your app is first run and then do something.

> every time if there is any update, I'd like to add more files to the app folder

If your `minSdkVersion` is 12 or higher, you should be able to register for `ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` in the manifest and then do something upon receipt of the broadcast.